# file handling runtime error - python in pycharm

Tags: python

My script program as folows-

```
fname = raw_input('Enter a file name: ')
f1 = open(fname)
for line in f1:
    line1 = line.capitalize()
    print line1
```

How to solve this error?

```
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>   File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script  
File "D:/Pycharm Projects/Files/p7.1.py", line 5, in <module>
    f1 = open(file_name) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'D:/Pycharm Projects/Files/fname\\mbox-short.text'
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. You just have to input a valid file path.

Comment: What do you input for file name? Does the file mbox-short.txt exist at the path "D:/Pycharm Projects/Files/fname"?

Comment: yes the file exists but then also the error persists

Answer (score 0):

'D:/Pycharm Projects/Files/fname\\mbox-short.text' does not look correctly formatted. Are your slashes correct?

Also a better way to read file is this:

```
with open(fname) as f1:
    for line in f1:
        print(line.capitalize())
```

Using with statement will ensure that your file handler is closed automatically after the use.